# violación de segmento en pandas al guardar excel de mas de 1,5 millones de lineas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Estoy parseando una serie de logs y convirtiendolos a archivos excel.
No me da ningún problema hasta que llego a un archivo en el que uno de los dataframes tiene 1,6 millones de lineas (previamente ha hecho uno de 1,3 millones sin problemas).

El mensaje de error lo lanza al finalizar el guardado, la linea de print llega a ejecutarse, la siguiente lo ignoro ya que no me da mas información ni sé como sacarla.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(savefile) as writer:
        df_log.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='log', index=False)
        debug_sheetname = 'debug'
        if len(df_debug) > 1000000:
            sheet = 0
            print('trimming large sheet page: ', len(df_debug))
            while len(df_debug) > 1000000:
                df_towrite = df_debug.loc[:1000000]
                print(f'saving debug sheet {debug_sheetname}')
                sheet += 1
                df_towrite.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=debug_sheetname, index=False)
                debug_sheetname = f'debug_{sheet + 1}' #<-- llega a esta linea como poco
                df_debug = df_debug.loc[1000000:]

        df_debug.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=debug_sheetname, index=False)
        df_timedelta.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='timedelta', index=False)
        print(f'Creating file {savefile}')
        filecreated = True
```

El error:

```
trimming large sheet page:  1657719
saving debug sheet debug
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

estoy usando:

- python3.9
- openpyxl==3.0.6
- pandas==1.2.2
- numpy==1.19.4
- Fedora32

Agradecería cualquier pista sobre lo que esta sucediendo, he logrado averiguar que el error es de alguna librería de C por el mensaje de error pero nada mas, no sé donde ni porque

Comment: Posiblemente sea un problema de memoria (y un bug en la implementación de la biblioteca C que guarda la excel, que rompe en vez de generar una excepción diciendo que no hay memoria). Si estás ejecutando en una máquina Unix, asegúrate de tener un archivo de _swap_ grande, a ver si eso ayuda. También puedes ir borrando variables en tu código a medida que dejes de necesitarlas, para liberar memoria. Monitoriza con `top` el uso de memoria mientras tu script se está ejecutando.

Comment: tengo 32GB de memoria física y 5GB de swap (la cual creo que es dinámica y aumenta si es necesario) no creo que la memoria sea un problema